# Compare time in Go

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a table contains column `created_at` I need to compare the time in this column with the now time for example:

```
result := database.DB.Where("code = ?", post.code).First(&post)

if result.CreatedAt < time.Now() {
        // do something
}
```

I got error in  my editor: `Invalid operation: result.CreatedAt > time.Now() (the operator > is not defined on Time)`

How can check if the date expires?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [time.After](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.After) or [time.Before](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Before).

[Playground example:](https://play.golang.com/p/iKz1Sch6rO1)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    created := time.Date(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    now := time.Now()
    if created.Before(now) {
        fmt.Println("do something")
    }
}
```

Comment: `time.Now().After(result.CreatedAt)`